# What is the logic behind this statement: for (--index; index >= 0; --index)?

Tags: c

I found this example in a C language book.
This code converts the input number base and stores it in an array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char base_digits[16] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};
    int converted_number[64];
    long int number_to_convert;
    int next_digit, base, index = 0;

    printf("type a number to be converted: \n");
    scanf("%ld", &number_to_convert);

    printf("Base\n");
    scanf("%i", &base);

    do 
    {
        converted_number[index] = number_to_convert % base;
        ++index;
        number_to_convert = number_to_convert / base;
    }
    while (number_to_convert != 0);

    // now display the number
    printf("converted number =  :");

    for (--index; index >= 0; --index ) 
    {
        next_digit = converted_number[index];
        printf("%c", base_digits[next_digit]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I can't understand the last for loop. It should help with reversing the array but I don't understand how!

What does this line mean: `for (--index; index >= 0; --index)`?

Comment: I’d like to add that it’s a book you should toss in the trash if you encountered a loop like that in it. **dasblinkenlight** has easily highlighted a better way, which any programmer worth his salt could have come up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that `for` header has three parts:

- The declaration/initialization part that gets executed once before the loop,
- The ending condition checker that gets executed before each iteration, and
- The part that advances the loop forward to the next iteration

Commonly, the declaration/initialization part sets up a new loop variable. However, it is not required to do so. In particular, when multiple loops share the same loop variable, the initialization portion adjusts the existing value or is missing altogether.

This is exactly what happens in your situation. The `do`/`while` loop advances `index` to one past the end of the array. If you need to start processing from the back of `converted_number`, you need to decrement `index` before going into the loop, and then also decrement it on each iteration.

Note that another possibility would be using a `while` loop with pre-decrement on the `index`:

```
while (index > 0) {
    next_digit = converted_number[--index];
    printf("%c", base_digits[next_digit]);
}
```

Comment: For you `while` loop, you want `index > 0`, as when it is `0`, you'll predecrement it to -1 and then access `converted_number[-1]`, leading to undefined behavior